# Trigger on contentdocumentlink on insert, makes checkbox true on account

Tags: apex

Trying to write a trigger on contentdocumentlink, which fires on insert and check a check box to true on account, but code doesn't seems to work.

Also getting compile error.

```
   public with sharing class contentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {
        public static void processOnInsert(list<ContentDocumentLink> newList) {
            list<ContentDocumentLink> contentList = new list<ContentDocumentLink>();
            set<id> accId = new set<id>();
            map<id,list<ContentDocumentLink>> parentContentMap = new map<id,list<ContentDocumentLink>>();
            set<id> contId = new set<id>();
            for(ContentDocumentLink nt : newList){
                if(nt.linkedentityid.getSobjectType() == Account.SObjectType){
                    accId.add(nt.linkedentityid);
                }
                if(nt.linkedentityid.getSobjectType() == Contact.SObjectType){
                    contId.add(nt.linkedentityid);  
                }
                if(parentContentMap.containsKey(nt.linkedentityid))
                    parentContentMap.get(nt.linkedentityid).add(nt);
                else
                    parentContentMap.put(nt.linkedentityid,new list<ContentDocumentLink>{nt});
            } 
            if(!accId.isEmpty()){
                //login for acc
                for(Account acc : [SELECT id,checkFiles__c FROM Account WHERE id IN : accId]){
                    if(parentContentMap.containsKey(acc.id)){
                        acc.checkFiles__c == true;// compile error
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually code doesn't work if it doesn't even compile -- and solving the problem is usually easier if you show the error

Comment: it's done..made a list of account and updated it